# C#: method to add WCF authentication, username + SSL?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security, wcf-client

I've written both a WCF client and a remote internet WCF server.

The remote WCF server is running WPF hosted in a traditional Windows Service wrapper (i.e. not IIS).

Currently, its working perfectly with basic HTTP binding. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 + .NET 4.0 + C#.

Can anyone point me in the direction of the right steps to alter my code so that I can add username + SSL authentication?

**EDIT:**

At the service end, I've overridden UserNamePasswordValidator as follows:

```
public class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
  public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Got to here");
  }
}
```

At the service end, I've specified a link to the username validation class:

```
  ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(PhiFeedServer.PhiFeed)); // ,baseAddress);

  const bool passswordAuthentication = true;
  if (passswordAuthentication)
  {
    // These two lines switch on username/password authentication (see custom class "CustomUserNameValidator" in common file PhiFeed.svc.cs)
    // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa354513.aspx
    serviceHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
    serviceHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new CustomUserNameValidator();
  }

  // Start the service
  serviceHost.Open();
```

At the client end:

```
  EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:20000/PhiFeed?wdsl"); 
  BasicHttpBinding serviceBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
  serviceBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 120);
  proxy = new PhiFeedClient(serviceBinding, endpointAddress);

  proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "myusername";
  proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "mypassword";
```

However, when I run everything, it never even calls the username validator - whats going on?

Comment: does it work on basichttp? i would personaly preffer wsHttpBinding or net.tcp binding. because you can use certificate with it :). it would be secured then

Comment: My current setup uses wsHttpBinding, so it can use a certificate. The code above was not working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am getting this right, you will need to play around with service behaviour.  I did that in 3.5 sp1 it should be the same in 4.0 i think.

read this:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/7d589542-277a-404e-ab46-222794422233/

Comment: The correct answer is below, but it seems a bit naff to answer my own question if your question may have given me clues :)

Answer (score 1):

Aha! Found the solution to my problem.

Microsoft provides example code which demonstrates how to add username/password + SSL authentication to a console app.

Search for "Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) and Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) Samples for .NET Framework 4", download, unzip into C:, then run the sample here:

C:\WF_WCF_Samples\WCF\Extensibility\Security\UserNamePasswordValidator\CS